# Branching with "if" statements

Tags: branch

I'm working on a problem learning to use "if" statements, and the code is supposed to tell us if a given number is positive or negative by resulting in  "True" or "False". Having some trouble identifying how to output this correctly, and I believe it is because I don't fully understand return() statements yet.

Here is the code so far:

```
    def is_positive(number):
      if (number) > 0:
        return number
```

The above returns "13" when given is_positive(13), I think I'm just a little lost on how to tell the code to return "True/ False?"

Apologies if I am missing something completely obvious here. Thanks!
Also still getting used to stack overflow searching, so any tips appreciated if this is a common question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change the return statement to `return True` or `return False`.

Comment: this also makes sense to me now haha. Thank you!

Comment: @CodyTumblin no problem! If my answer has helped you can you please mark it as answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just change your return statement to

```
return (number) > 0
```